# Dynamic faceted search

Tags: jquery, asp.net, linq

I'm assigned to make an overview of open jobs.
I made a Class called Job, I load a List that contains all the open Jobs from the SQL Server.
My boss wants me to make a dynamic faceted search.

For example a Job has a Function (Sales Manager), a Function Area (Sales), a Location (Washington)... 
The list (the Jobs) is dynamic, the filter options are dynamic (distinct properties of my Job objects).

How would I go and code this the best way? Since my controls are dynamic it will be a pain to recreate all the dynamic checkboxed in the On_Init.

IMO client side would be the best way (I have a  of all the jobs and make the script filter based on html classes).
Please note its possible that there are ~500 job openings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this JavaScript library, which uses Underscore.js and jQuery.
http://eikes.github.com/facetedsearch/

It's not 100% what I needed, I needed to add some styling support and allows output to differen't element.